# 6x6 block matrix inversion

Tags: python, matrix, linear-algebra, matrix-inverse

I'm facing the inversion of a 6x6 matrix which can also be represented as a symmetric block matrix as following:

[image]

Each of the P sub matrices is then a 3x3 matrix. P12 and P21 are equal so that P is symmetric. I would like to exploit this form to compute the inverse P matrix in an efficient way. Until now I'm using using the inv() function from Scipy directly on P but, having profiled my code and considering that I have to invert this type of matrices thousands of times in the code I would wish for a better way. Looking up online I found a formula using Schur complements as follow:

[image]

I'm wondering if using this strategy will be more computationally efficient then inverting the 6x6 matrix after assembling it. Since the blocks are only 3x3 I could also think of using formulas for calculating the inverse of the blocks, and then use them in the formula represented in the second picture.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it belongs to https://math.stackexchange.com

Comment: I wonder if you reframe the question to be about time-order complexity (big-O notation)?

Comment: Is inverting such tiny matrices a bottleneck? A good inversion routine should invert them very quickly. When contemplating an optimisation you should measure how much time the un-optimised code is taking.  Moreover if you implement your alternate method in python even if the algorithm is better the code could be slower than the library code, which I may well come down C code. Finally note that the formula you give assumes that A is invertible. But A=0 B=C=I D=0 gives an invertible P -- P is its own inverse -- but neither A nor B are invertible

Comment: @rajah9 No I'm not interested in big-O since the matrix is always 6x6 and my code doesn't have to be scalable. Also to answer dmuir, It's not taking long to invert such a small matrix, but my code performs many small calculations and this one in particular it's the most expensive one. I'm just wondering if someone is aware of more specialized ways or also libraries (with interfaces to python) to take care of such a structure (block symmetric matrixes)

Comment: Note that the usual definition of symmetric matrix is that it equals its own transpose. Your P will be symmetric in that sense iff P11 and P22 are symmetric and P12 = P21' Is your matrix symmetric in that sense? Do you know any more about P? Is it, for example, positive definite? Getting performance out of a matrix inversion routine often comes down to exploiting all the knowledge you have about the particular matrix.

Comment: good point @dmuir, no, the matrix is not symmetric in the usual sense, what I mean by "symmetric" is that P12 = P21 but P11 and P22 can be anything. The matrix is certainly positively defined.